# How to Hide Keyboard in WinRT by Code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, keyboard

In my winRT C# app i have a textbox, when the text box is disabled the visual keyboard must hide. but it is not working as expected.

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="458,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="98" Width="389" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp_1"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
                (sender as TextBox).IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working as expected"? I created a TextBox with the above event handler and as soon as I tapped Enter, the control got disabled and the keyboard closed.

Comment: @DamirArh, but not for me, the keyboard is not getting closed

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a sample code, you can check it against your code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c)

Comment: This sample shows how to react when the virtual keyboard appears. I think vibeeshanRC wants to prevent it from appearing at all.

Comment: Ur is an ancient city in Iraq.  Do avoid text-speak and link-only answers in an SO post.  We've got high standards here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to focus to another UIElement via this this:

```
    Descendents(MainFrame).OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault().Focus(FocusState.Pointer);


    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(DependencyObject root)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
            yield return child;
            foreach (DependencyObject descendent in Descendents(child))
                yield return descendent;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a form with a few TextBox fields. In one of them, I don't want that the application shows the digital keyboard.

To prevent this, I have specified the property IsReadOnly="True".

I have used IsReadOnly property instead of IsEnabled="False", because IsEnabled disables the Tapped event and it doesn't stop when we tab between controls.

```
<TextBox Name="tbx" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxDefaultStyle}" TabIndex="13" IsReadOnly="True" />
```